# jQuery dropdown ajax search on keydown is 'one step behind'

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a dropdown list which is echoed by a php file through ajax. A user on website can search his friends with this dropdown. I have the following code (validation isn't shown) :

```
var textbox = $('#participant-textbox');
$(function(){
                    textbox.keydown(function(e) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type:"POST",
                            url:"sources/friend_search.php",
                            data:{value:document.getElementById('participant-textbox').value}
                        })

                            .done(function(rtrn) {
                                $('.invite-participants-dropdown').html(rtrn);
                            });

                        if(!DropdownState)
                            {
                                dropdown.show();
                                DropdownState=true;
                            }

                    });
});
```

Although this works, but the ajax is one step behind. What I mean is that :

When I type 'a' into the textbox, it doesn't show anything.

[image]

When I type 'ab' , it should show 'abhishek' (I use LIKE clause for search) , but it searches only for `%a%` , and thus shows all friends with a `a` in their name.

[image]

When I type 'abh' , it should now search for `%abh%` , whereas it searches for `%ab%` (which should have been the case in the previous request).

[image]

I cannot think of any other way to explain this. What am I missing here?

Comment: use keyup event for tex box

Comment: @user790454 What would be the difference between `keydown` and `keyup` ?

Comment: keydown :
Fires when the user depresses a key. It repeats while the user keeps the key depressed.
keyup
Fires when the user releases a key, after the default action of that key has been performed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [keyup()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp) instead of keydown

```
keydown
Fires when the user depresses a key. It repeats while the user keeps the key depressed.

keyup
Fires when the user releases a key, after the default action of that key has been performed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Keyup` event instead of `keydown`

```
 textbox.keyup(function(e) {...
```

**keydown** : Fires when the user depresses a key. It repeats while the user keeps the key depressed. \
**keyup**
Fires when the user releases a key, after the default action of that key has been performed.

For more details see [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html).